# QAction: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm getting the error

> QAction: No such file or directory

when I try to compile a project for plugin (C++ Library template). Weird, because I have a project for my app which also includes this header and there is no error. What might cause this?

Comment: Maybe it's because of different header file search algorithm implementation.

Comment: Make sure your that your include paths are correct. What are they?

Comment: @netrom whay do you mean ? from .pro PATH settings ? sorry i'm new

Comment: @develoops: let me put in another way. Do you use Qt for other stuff which works, i.e. it finds the headers?

Comment: Do you use qmake? If yes, paste the .pro file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you have the right include paths set up.

If you use QMake the `*.pro` should contain these settings if you want to include files from `QtGui`. They should be set by default but some templates may not set them.

```
CONFIG += qt
QT += gui
```

If you use another build system then make sure that you either use

```
#include <QtGui/QAction>
```

or you add `$QTDIR/include/QtGui` and not just `$QTDIR/include` to your include path

Comment: thanks . i added : CONFIG += qt (QT += gui , was already) , and everything works fine

Answer (score 11):

For me I had some stale `moc_` and `ui_` files left over from compiling under a different version and configuration of Qt, so removing them solved the problem for me.

```
rm moc_* ui_* *.o
```