# When compiling get error: 'QtGui/QAction' file not found #include <QtGui/QAction>

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I just installed Mac OS X 10.8.3 and Qt Creator 3, XCode, and XCode command line tools. I'm trying to compile a project that works on another computer but each time I go to "build all" I get `error: 'QtGui/QAction' file not found`
 in `#include <QtGui/QAction>`

I tried adding the second and third line in the .pro file but it didn't help

```
QT       += core gui opengl
CONFIG += qt
QT += gui
TARGET = BasicOpenGL
TEMPLATE = app
```

UPDATE: I also tried this .pro file and it didn't work

```
QT       += core gui opengl
QT += widgets
TARGET = BasicOpenGL
TEMPLATE = app
```

I should say this is my first time attempting development on mac.

Compile Output from Qt

```
Versions/A/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I. -F/Users/john/Qt/5.2.0/clang_64/lib -o mainwindow.o ../Framework/mainwindow.cpp
In file included from ../Framework/mainwindow.cpp:2:
../Framework/ui_mainwindow.h:14:10: fatal error: 'QtGui/QAction' file not found
#include <QtGui/QAction>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [mainwindow.o] Error 1
15:51:32: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project BasicOpenGL (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

UPDATE: I got it to work but with all the screwing around I'm not exactly sure what did it. I started with a fresh mac image, installed system updates, installed xcode, installed xcode command line tools, installed QT Creator 3.0, installed QT libraries 4.8.1, setup the compilers in QT Creator.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274514/qaction-no-such-file-or-directory you must add "QT += widgets" to the .pro file for Qt5.

Comment: Do you have all the libraries you need? They are not included with Qt Creator

Comment: @gartenriese I don't think so. I tried following [these instructions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-mac.html) but find them incomplete. "run the ./configure script in the package directory." I couldn't find that and don't know what a package directory is.

Comment: Package directory is referring to the unpacked directory from archive mentioned in step 1 in the instructions (grab the archive [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads) -- link "Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Mac" should be the right one).

Comment: I installed Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Mac by running the Qt.mpkg file, but still same problem

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Qt5, `QAction` header is in `QtWidgets` include sub-directory, not in `QtGui` (that's true for Qt4). Though you don't actually need to specify include sub-directories since `qmake` will handle that for you. You just need to add `QT += widgets` to your `.pro` file.

Comment: Can you check if the failing compile command contains `-I<PATH_TO_QT5_INSTALL>/QtWidgets`? (It's under "Compile Output" in Qt Creator at the bottom status bar.)

Comment: No I don't think so. I updated the question with the output of the compiler.

Comment: same problem with me, I can see QAction in QtWidget directory I have QT += widgets in my pro file still same error.

Comment: Using QT Creator, setting the version to Qt5 and rebuilding the project worked for me

Comment: I had this issue with peercoin-qt. To fix this I was required to cleanup `build` directory and re-run `qmake` as it doesn't seem to update those auto-generated header files.

Answer (score 22):

Try doing a `make clean` followed by a `make`.  I had this exact problem on a Windows 7 system, and this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Set the version to Qt5, change all `#include<QtQui/*>`s into `#include<QtWidgets/*>`.
And add `QT += widgets` in your .pro file.
Rebuild the project, when you get the error again, tap into the error message, and change the `#include<QtQui/*>`s into `#include<QtWidgets/*>` too.

Comment: And also delete all the "QApplication::UnicodeUTF8" in ui_*.h.

Answer (score 2):

Some answers here say that you have to change include from `<QtGui/QAction>` to `<QtWidgets/QAction>`.

It was the case when you compile under QT-5. But after QT-6 was released you have to do the opposite in QT-6 application.

Now you have to change `<QtWidgets/QAction>` to `<QtGui/QAction>`, because now QAction is located in QtGui folder in QT-6.

Although my answer is not related to your very old question, as you had QT-4 problem, still your question pops up first in Google hence I'm posting my answer for those StackOverflow visitors who have same problem but with compiling QT-5 project under QT-6, as I did.

Comment: This answer should be the one that is accepted as the solution.