# Static QT Compilation problems

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I created a app in QT Creator and am trying to build a distributable mac app with it, but I keep getting this error:

```
./mainwindow.h:4:10: fatal error: 'QMainWindow' file not found
#include <QMainWindow>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

First I `cd` to the projects build directory folder and invoke the statically compiled version of qmake:

```
/Volumes/StaticQT/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/bin/qmake -config release /PathOfFoo.pro
```

I then run `make` and receive the error as highlighted above. I've tried adding:

```
INCLUDEPATH = "/Volumes/BackupSG/StaticQT/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/include"
```

to the .pro file to specify where it should draw stuff from. I'm not sure if it's that qmake/make isn't finding the right dir or what.

Note: I also have the same issue with the non-static version.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've read several other questions about this, but they are mostly all for older versions of qt.

Edit: The original problem was solved by the answer of adding `QT += widgets` to the .pro file, and got further into compilation before it ran into another similar issue:

```
/$paths/ui_mainwindow.h:13:10: fatal error: 'QtGui/QAction' file not found
#include <QtGui/QAction>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Per the comments on the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551557/when-compiling-get-error-qtgui-qaction-file-not-found-include-qtgui-qaction?noredirect=1&lq=1), the step at which make fails does have `-I<PATH_TO_QT5_INSTALL>/QtWidgets`.

Comment: QMainWindow is not in the /qtbase/include folder.

Comment: See edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with static Qt. Your project file doesn't include the necessary `widgets` module:

```
# Foo.pro
QT += widgets
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = Foo
SOURCES += ...
HEADERS += ...
# etc
```

After fixing this, re-run qmake as such changes to the project file are not automatically detected.

If you wish to support Qt 4, you'll want something like:

```
QT += gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

> I've tried adding
>   `INCLUDEPATH = "/Volumes/BackupSG/StaticQT/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0/qtbase/include"`

Don't do that. You've got qmake to do it for you. If it doesn't, it merely means your project file is broken.

Finally, the path `<QtGui/QAction>` is invalid. It's a holdover from Qt 4, but even there it wasn't necessary: it should have simply been `<QAction>`. Change it to `<QAction>` and you'll be set. If that file is generated (it looks like it), you're attempting to reuse `uic` output from Qt 4: don't do that. Qt 5's `uic` won't ever generate that line. Add the `.ui` files to the project, and get rid of the `ui_foo.h` files:

```
# Foo.pro
...
FORMS += foo.ui bar.ui
```

As a rule of thumb, your project should only ever have two forms of Qt includes:

```
#include <QtModule>
#include <QClass>

#include <QtModule/QClass>   // Don't! Use <QClass> instead
#include <QtModule/qclass.h> // Don't! Use <QClass> instead
#include <qclass.h>          // Don't! Use <QClass> instead
```

Note that Qt's own sources and generated output break that rule, but it's done for technical reasons that do not apply to the code you yourself write.